# How to call a c function from name , which is stored in a char* pointer?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I wanted to dynamically call a function by its name , e.g , suppose have the following function and string:

```
void do_fork()
{
   printf ("Fork called.\n");

}

char *pFunc = "do_fork";
```

Now i need to call `do_fork()` just by `*pFunc`. So is that possible ?

Either C/C++ code is welcomed , many thanks !

Comment: Just possible by using hacks like GetProcAddress (Windows) and dlsym (UNIX), but almost certainly a bad idea.  Use a function pointer instead.

Comment: @cdarke: That assumes that using a function pointer is even *possible* for his use case. dlsym (and friends) are the best fit for this situation; because they actually do what he asks about; and not something related that requires an entirely different situation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Neither C nor C++ have enough reflection to do this out of the box, so you will have to implement your own scheme.

In C++, the more or less canonical way to do that is using a map of strings to function pointers. Something like this:

```
typedef void (*func_t)();
typedef std::map<std::string,func_t> func_map_t;

// fill the map
func_map_t func_map;
func_map["do_fork"] = &do_fork;
func_map["frgl"] = &frgl;

// search a function in the map
func_map_t::const_iterator it = func_map.find("do_fork");
if( it == func_map.end() ) throw "You need error handling here!"
(*it->second)();
```

Of course, this is limited to functions with exactly the same signature. However, this limitation can be somewhat lifted (to encompass reasonably compatible signatures) by using `std::function` and `std::bind` instead of a plain function pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Not entirely sure if it's what you're looking for but you could easily use `dlopen` and `dlsym`.

```
void *dlsym(void *restrict handle, const char *restrict name);
```

> The dlsym() function shall obtain the
>   address of a symbol defined within an
>   object made accessible through a
>   dlopen() call. The handle argument is
>   the value returned from a call to
>   dlopen() (and which has not since been
>   released via a call to dlclose()), and
>   **`name` is the symbol's name as a
>   character string.**

That said, it usually doesn't come to this in C so you likely don't actually need it.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible, but it's not entirely easy.

What you need to do is to compile your binary for dynamic binding; and then getting the function with dlsym, as per @cnicutar's answer.

There are caveats, of course; but if the function in question is in a dynamically linked library with a path guaranteed to be known at runtime (a plug-in or extension module would match this), it's a fairly safe way of doing things.

dlsym-ing function in the active executable, OTOH, gets hairy.

Answer (score 0):

If it must be done using the name of the function and you don't want to go about cnicutar's way, you could go with this method:

Compile each function in its own *.exe file. Use system(PATH_TO_FUNCTION_EXECUTABLE/FUNCTION_NAME) to call the executable.

Answer (score 0):

If you know all the functions you'll need to call, and they're placed in one program, you can use this:

```
void do_fork()
{
    printf ("Fork called.\n");
}

void callFunc(char *funcName)
{
    if (strcmp(funcName, "do_fork") == 0) do_fork();
}

int main()
{
    char *pFunc = "do_fork";
    callFunc(pFunc);
    return 0;
}
```